# Gimp Batch Layer Automation

Tags: batch-processing, gimp

I am currently using GIMP to layer two photos into one photo file for a work project. I have over 7000 107x80 JPG images that I need to place on a 160 x 100 PNG background that has a logo on it and saved as the JPG file name. The 107x80 JPG needs to be placed to the left of the logo on the background. I have been doing this one at a time but it is very time comsuming. I have used BIMP to resize all the JPG images and would really like to find a way to use BIMP to automate this process or find another program that can do this process. I have seen several post about Imagemagick but I am not very good with console based programs. Is there a way to do this in GIMP or another Photoshop program that can do batch processing to place the photo in an exact spot on the background? Would it be better to get Photoshop and do a Macro? Thank you for your help [JPG on background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFSOb.png)  [Background PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW28n.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImageMagick to composite one image at some exact location on another image. ImageMagick convert can do this operation and is command line driven. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#convert. The convert process can be scripted to loop over each of your images. Or if you have the same background or the same overlay image, then you can process a whole folder of files using the mogrify command. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify and http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify_compose.  If you provide a pair of images and the location where you want the one image to be placed on the other image. I can give you more direct commands.